# Chrome - containing div has rounded corners in CSS, but not rendering as rounded

Tags: css

I have this as my rule for rounded:

```
.rounded { border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; }
```

On my site I'm working on, http://urlme.cc/movies6, if you view it in Chrome, each movie div has the class "rounded", but, the div has straight edges.

In Firefox, it's rounding correctly. Please see image comparison below.

You can view source / inspect elements on the above link, but, the html looks basically like this:

```
<div class="movie rounded">
  <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
  <div class="details">1 hr, 20 min</div>
</div>
```

[image: Chrome vs. Firefox comparison of rounded corners]

**Question**: any reason why Chrome is not rounding those div.movie corners, while Firefox is? Thanks!

Comment: Based on the minimal snippets provided it should be behaving. Since you're using chrome, have you tried to use the "inspect element" tool to see what styles are being applied? It's not inconceivable that your border-radius is being overridden by a competing style.

Comment: It's a small thing, but be sure to order your border radius rules with the vendor prefixed versions (e.g. -moz-border-radius) first, then the non-prefixed versions. As browsers solidify support for properties, and drop the need for the prefixes, the un-prefixed rule would win.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking off `position:relative` on **.movie** seemed to do it in Chrome Developer Tools.